# Image Source broken in JS, using MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using MongoDB to upload and store images in Javascript.

However, when the image gets uploaded it appears in the inspect element as "/image.png". When you remove the slash in inspect element the image I uploaded appears.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify a little bit more information in order to get the best possible answer.

My first question would be: "How consistent is the backslash?"

If it's in every single DB entry, then prior to pushing it to the page, I'd strip the backslash using something like the below:

```
var retImgSrc = retImgSrc.substr(1);
```

If the DB entry isn't consistent, or you find the consistency isn't to your liking, the logic may need to change.

Hope that helps